# text box value disappears/empties on PHP validation

Tags: php

Hi I have a structure as follows. The issue is once the error message is displayed, the text box content disappears and need to re-type a value again. I need to retain the original text box value/content as it is whilst the message is displayed. How do you think I should change? Thanks.

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['subN'])) {
$InNo = $_POST['invc_no'];

$MSG = '';
if($InNo == "") 
{$MSG = 'Invoice number is required';} 
else
{//some code to save data to a database}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div id="msgBox"><?php if(!empty($MSG)) echo $MSG; ?></div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php htmlentities('InNo')?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="subN" id="subN" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Often it is much mor elegant to submit the form using ajax calls in background and just leaving the filled form until succcess has been signaled.

Comment: @arkascha That would be another question. He's just not echoing the right value -.-

Comment: @SaulMartínez: I am well aware what the problem here is. All I did is to point out that though the current strategy can be fixed to work there are better alternatives.

Comment: I agree, just thought it was out of scope, didn't mean to be rude. Even with the same script, adding a simple ajax call would improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php htmlentities('InNo')?>">
```

To

```
<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['invc_no'])?>">
```

**Second Solution:**

Put as below

```
$InNo = ''; // if you doesn't put any value into text box, then you will get undefined error while you use this variable later on so give initial value to null

if(isset($_POST['subN'])) {
 continue ....
}
else{
 continue ..
}

<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php echo htmlentities($InNo); ?>">
```

Comment: can you really post InNo? Imean should it be $_POST['invo_val'] or  $_POST['InNo'] ?

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: invc_no in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\ss\docs\addInvo.php</b> on line ...........what this error could be?

Comment: you missed the echo. With that It works the way expected. do correct for me to accept.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['inNo']` in your input box:

```
<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?= $_POST['inNo'] ?>">
```

Your are not echoing the value, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to put echo there.

Change this,

```
<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php htmlentities('InNo')?>">
```

To

```
<input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php echo htmlentities('InNo')?>">
```